# log4js https logging endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

In log4js is there any option to use HTTP endpoint for logging the information. Like in Winston you have HTTP transport for logging to remote HTTP endpoint by specifying host:port, is there something similar in log4js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is broad, is there a specific logging protocol you are interested in?

There is [GELF appender](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/blob/master/lib/appenders/gelf.js) you could use, it is based on UDP though.

If you are looking for something simple as just sending `POST` requests to a private HTTP server, then that can actually be implemented without many difficulties. Just take [`console`](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/blob/master/lib/appenders/console.js) appender for an example, and change the `console.log` to HTTP Post function.

Comment: A code on making POST requests in Node.js? Look no further: http://www.sitepoint.com/making-http-requests-in-node-js/